# Divide array into smaller consecutive parts such that NEO value is maximal

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

On this years [Bubble Cup](http://www.bubblecup.org/) (finished) there was the problem [NEO](http://www.spoj.com/problems/NEO2/) (which I couldn't solve), which asks

Given array with n integer elements. We divide it into several part (may be 1), each part is a consecutive of elements. The NEO value in that case is computed by: Sum of value of each part. Value of a part is sum all elements in this part multiple by its length.

Example: We have array: [ 2 3 -2 1 ]. If we divide it like: [2 3] [-2 1]. Then NEO = (2 + 3) * 2 + (-2 + 1) * 2 = 10 - 2 = 8.

The number of elements in array is smaller then `10^5` and the numbers are integers between `-10^6` and `10^6`

I've tried something like divide and conquer to constantly split array into two parts if it increases the maximal NEO number otherwise return the NEO of the whole array. But unfortunately the algorithm has worst case O(N^2) complexity (my implementation is below) so I'm wondering whether there is a better solution

EDIT: My algorithm (greedy) doesn't work, taking for example `[1,2,-6,2,1]` my algorithm returns the whole array while to get the maximal NEO value is to take parts `[1,2],[-6],[2,1]` which gives NEO value of `(1+2)*2+(-6)+(1+2)*2=6`

```
#include <iostream>
int maxInterval(long long int suma[],int first,int N)
{
    long long int max = -1000000000000000000LL; 
    long long int curr;
    if(first==N) return 0;
    int k;
    for(int i=first;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(first>0) curr = (suma[i]-suma[first-1])*(i-first+1)+(suma[N-1]-suma[i])*(N-1-i); // Split the array into elements from [first..i] and [i+1..N-1] store the corresponding NEO value
        else curr = suma[i]*(i-first+1)+(suma[N-1]-suma[i])*(N-1-i); // Same excpet that here first = 0 so suma[first-1] doesn't exist
        if(curr > max) max = curr,k=i; // find the maximal NEO value for splitting into two parts
    }
    if(k==N-1) return max; // If the max when we take the whole array then return the NEO value of the whole array
    else
    {
        return maxInterval(suma,first,k+1)+maxInterval(suma,k+1,N); // Split the 2 parts further if needed and return it's sum
    }
}
int main() {
    int T;
    std::cin >> T;
    for(int j=0;j<T;j++) // Iterate over all the test cases
    {
        int N;
        long long int NEO[100010]; // Values, could be long int but just to be safe
        long long int suma[100010]; // sum[i] = sum of NEO values from NEO[0] to NEO[i]
        long long int sum=0;
        int k;
        std::cin >> N;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            std::cin >> NEO[i];
            sum+=NEO[i];
            suma[i] = sum;
        }
        std::cout << maxInterval(suma,0,N) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Getting _only_ O(n^2) here would be pretty good: brute force is O(n 2^n), from the number of [compositions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of _n_.

Comment: Your time complexity is not O(n^2), sadly

Comment: are all the parts of the array with the same length or the length is arbitrary ?

Comment: @Spektre Length is arbitrary.

Comment: @PhamTrung I've had a few mistakes in my code (used 0 instead of first and such) which increased complexity exponentially, after fixing the mistakes I tried my algorithm for input 1 10000 followed by 10000 numbers -1 since then the array is split in 10000 parts with length 1,  it entered the recursion 19999 times and counting the number of total iterations it was near 150000 seems pretty solid. Though I think my algorithm doesn't work for every output

Comment: Ahh, I saw your approach is greedy, greedily split the array by choosing the largest part. Maybe using interval tree could help to find the largest part faster, which reduces your program to O(nlogn), however I am not sure about the correctness still.

Comment: I believe your solution works for every conf. Try to imagine what would happen if you split one of the final *parts*. That would reduce sum.

Comment: As a small optimization, you can skip over negatives.

Comment: @Yola I've just found a counterexample if I take 1 2 -6 2 1 my algorithm chooses the whole array which gives 0*6 = 0 while the optimum is [1,2],[-6],[2,1] = (1+2)*2+(-6)+(2+1)*2=6. Back to the drawing board I guess :P

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried dynamic programming approach, but it needs to much memory and failed time constraints.

Comment: I added some code to my answer. Could you possibly try it in SPOJ? (Maybe convert to c++? ...I have very little practice reading and writing to std-io :)

Comment: @גלעדברקן Javascript std-io seems scary so I converted it to C++, I've put it on ideone [here](https://ideone.com/4fkSse) tried it on SPOJ it exceeds the time limit (can't link directly to submission so here's the link of my latest [submissions](http://www.spoj.com/status/kingw3/) ). I'll try looking for optimizations to your code later (perhaps it's on the edge of time limit) as I'm mega tried atm.

Comment: oh, wow, thanks! I'll think about it some more  :)

Comment: Are you getting any feedback about the correctness of the results of גלעד ברקן's method, or just that the time limit was exceeded ?

Comment: @m69 No, just that the program took to long to execute (SPOJ is pretty terrible at feedback) it could be for any reason including bugs in program i.e infinite loops or waiting for input (which most likely isn't the case here).

Comment: I added more info at the end of my anewer about the blog I found with the crux of the optimisation.

Comment: @גלעדברקן tried the compacting non negative numbers mentioned at the end and still tle >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a complete solution but should provide some helpful direction.

1. Combining two groups that each have a positive sum (or one of the sums is non-negative) would always yield a bigger NEO than leaving them separate:

   `m * a + n * b < (m + n) * (a + b) where a, b > 0 (or a > 0, b >= 0); m and n are subarray lengths`
2. Combining a group with a negative sum with an entire group of non-negative numbers always yields a greater NEO than combining it with only part of the non-negative group. But excluding the group with the negative sum could yield an even greater NEO:

   `[1, 1, 1, 1] [-2] => m * a + 1 * (-b)`

   Now, imagine we gradually move the dividing line to the left, increasing the sum b is combined with. While the expression on the right is negative, the NEO for the left group keeps decreasing. But if the expression on the right gets positive, relying on our first assertion (see 1.), combining the two groups would always be greater than not.
3. Combining negative numbers alone in sequence will always yield a smaller NEO than leaving them separate:

   `-a - b - c ... = -1 * (a + b + c ...)`

   `l * (-a - b - c ...) = -l * (a + b + c ...)`

   `-l * (a + b + c ...) < -1 * (a + b + c ...) where l > 1; a, b, c ... > 0`

`O(n^2)` time, `O(n)` space JavaScript code:

```js
function f(A){
  A.unshift(0);

  let negatives = [];
  let prefixes = new Array(A.length).fill(0);
  let m = new Array(A.length).fill(0);

  for (let i=1; i<A.length; i++){
    if (A[i] < 0)
      negatives.push(i);

    prefixes[i] = A[i] + prefixes[i - 1];
    m[i] = i * (A[i] + prefixes[i - 1]);

    for (let j=negatives.length-1; j>=0; j--){
      let negative = prefixes[negatives[j]] - prefixes[negatives[j] - 1];
      let prefix = (i - negatives[j]) * (prefixes[i] - prefixes[negatives[j]]);

      m[i] = Math.max(m[i], prefix + negative + m[negatives[j] - 1]);
    }
  }

  return m[m.length - 1];
}

console.log(f([1, 2, -5, 2, 1, 3, -4, 1, 2]));
console.log(f([1, 2, -4, 1]));
console.log(f([2, 3, -2, 1]));
console.log(f([-2, -3, -2, -1]));
```

#### Update

[This blog](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/59694?locale=en) provides that we can transform the dp queries from

```
dp_i = sum_i*i + max(for j < i) of ((dp_j + sum_j*j) + (-j*sum_i) + (-i*sumj))
```

to

```
dp_i = sum_i*i + max(for j < i) of (dp_j + sum_j*j, -j, -sum_j) ⋅ (1, sum_i, i)
```

which means we could then look at each iteration for an already seen vector that would generate the largest dot product with our current information. The math alluded to involves convex hull and farthest point query, which are beyond my reach to implement at this point but will make a study of.

Comment: Thanks for the link it's extremely helpful, I'll try implementing my own solution if I succeed I'll post the answer here.

Comment: @kingW3 yea, it's fascinating how the computational geometry relates to these number queries. I'm trying to visualize it myself. (By the way, in case you're having difficulty, notice that user dacin21 posted the full code in that blog :)